# I want to Change ubuntu 14.04 from 64 bit to 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, 64-bit

How can I Change Ubuntu 14.04 from 64 bit to 32 bit ?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It will most likely be slower than the current version...

Comment: I have 2GB RAM in My machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because you only have 2Gs of RAM doesn't mean that you need to downgrade to 32bit-
(In fact, downgrading isn't likely to solve your real problem)
Allow me to offer an alternative solution:

**Use a lighter desktop environment, such as LDXE or XFCE**

If you wanted to try this alternative first, simply run the following in a terminal:

`sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop`

--or--

`sudo apt-get install xubuntu-desktop`

for LDXE and XFCE, respectively.

You see, the default Ubuntu desktop - Unity - is what requires more than 2GB of RAM -- 
If your machine boots the 64 bit version, that's good - ! - but if it doesn't run very well, that's because Unity wants more than 2GB of RAM, and downgrading to 32bit isn't going to change that fact...

There is also [LXQT](http://lxqt.org/) coming soon, which you should also be able to run with just two gigs of RAM.

Answer (score 6):

You will need to reinstall Ubuntu using the [32 bit version](http://releases.ubuntu.com/14.04/ubuntu-14.04-desktop-i386.iso), make sure you backup all important data first.